# Json iteration Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json string
{"email" : "Hello", "username" : "Not taken"}

how do I iterate through this json to display the text (Like Hello)

I want to display the following text

Email : Hello
Username : Not taken

I tried the following:

```
    arr = json
    $.each(arr, function(k, v) {
      message += k + ':' + v + '<br />';  
    });
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: You'll have to parse the json first (if it is actually json).

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the JSON string to a Javascript object. Use `JSON.parse()`.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Script:

```js
var json = '{"email" : "Hello", "username" : "Not taken"}',
    arr = window.JSON.parse( json ),
    message = '';

$.each(arr, function(k, v) {
    message += k + ': ' + v + '<br />';  
});

document.getElementById( 'message' ).innerHTML = message;
```

#### HTML:

```html
<div id="message"></div>
```